# Drawing lines, with arrowheads, at arbitrary angles with respect to the positive x-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I am trying to get `TikZ` to draw two lines, with arrowheads, on the Cartesian plane.  I have drawn a square, with gray edges, and I want the tip of the arrowheads to be on an edge of the square.  In particular, I want to include the six commands following the comment

```
"The following code is for placing arrowheads at the ends of the line segments."
```

`TikZ` is not compiling them. (This can be an illustrative example using the `intersections` package.)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,backgrounds}


\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0pt,p/.style={circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt}]

\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (-3.75,0) +(-0.25cm,0) -- (3.75,0) -- +(0.25cm,0) node[below right] {$x$};

\clip (-3.75,-3.75) rectangle (3.75,3.75);

\draw[gray,dashed,line width=0.1pt] (-3.75,3.75) -- (3.75,3.75);
\draw[gray,dashed,line width=0.1pt] (-3.75,-3.75) -- (3.75,-3.75);
\draw[gray,dashed,line width=0.1pt] (-3.75,-3.75) -- (-3.75,3.75);
\draw[gray,dashed,line width=0.1pt] (3.75,-3.75) -- (3.75,3.75);

\draw[draw=blue!30,-latex] (0,0) -- (142:5);
\draw[draw=blue!30,-latex] (0,0) -- (-38:5);
\draw[draw=green!50,-latex] (0,0) -- (52:5);
\draw[draw=green!50,-latex] (0,0) -- (-128:5);

\coordinate[p,label={[fill=white]below right:$O$}] (O) at (0,0);

\coordinate (A) at (0:1);
\coordinate (B) at (52:1);
\path pic[draw, angle radius=5mm,"$\phi$",angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = A--O--B};

\coordinate (a) at (180:1);
\coordinate (b) at (142:1);
\path pic[draw, angle radius=5mm,"$\theta$",angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = b--O--a};

\coordinate (P) at (142:1);
\coordinate (Q) at (52:1);

\coordinate (R) at ($(O)!4mm! -45:(P)$);
\draw (R) -- ($(O)!(R)!(P)$);
\draw (R) -- ($(O)!(R)!(Q)$);

%The following code makes the right-angle mark and "colors" the inside of it white.
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (0,3.75) +(0,0.25cm) node[above right] {$y$} -- (0,-3.75) -- +(0,-0.25cm);
\filldraw[fill=white] (O.center) -- ($(O)!(R)!(P)$) -- (R) -- ($(O)!(R)!(Q)$) -- cycle;
\end{scope}


%The following code is for placing arrowheads at the ends of the line segments.
%\path[name intersections={of=(-3.75,3.75) -- (3.75,3.75) and (0,0) -- (52:5), by=intersection-1}];
%\path[name intersections={of=(3.75,3.75) -- (3.75,-3.75) and (0,0) -- (-38:5), by=intersection-2}];
%\path[name intersections={of=(-3.75,-3.75) -- (3.75,-3.75) and (0,0) -- (-128:5), by=intersection-3}];
%\path[name intersections={of=(-3.75,3.75) -- (-3.75,-3.75) and (0,0) -- (142:5), by=intersection-4}];

%\draw[draw=green!50,latex-latex] (intersection-1) -- (intersection-3);
%\draw[draw=blue!30,latex-latex] (intersection-2) -- (intersection-4);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You want to put the arrow heads on those blue and green lines?

Comment: @Harish Kumar  Yes.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it) effort for comparison.  The idea is that you set the angle `phi` and everything else adjusts automatically.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);
u := 1cm;
% defime the paths we need and a value for phi..
path xx, yy, box, ray;
xx = (left--right) scaled 4u;
yy = xx rotated 90;
box = unitsquare shifted -(1/2,1/2) scaled 7u;
ray = origin -- right scaled 7u;
numeric phi;
phi = 57.3; 

% first draw axes and box
drawoptions(withcolor .7 white);
drawdblarrow xx;
drawdblarrow yy;
draw box dashed evenly;
drawoptions();

% now draw the angle marks so they are underneath the main lines
% angle marks assume 0 < phi < 90...
path angle_mark[]; 
angle_mark1 = (1u,0) {up} .. (1u,0) rotated phi;
angle_mark2 = (-u,0) {up} .. (-u,0) rotated (phi-90);
angle_mark3 = unitsquare scaled 3/8 u rotated phi;
draw angle_mark1;
draw angle_mark2;
unfill angle_mark3; 
draw angle_mark3;

% now the main lines
for i=0 upto 3:
  drawarrow ray rotated (phi+90i) cutafter box withcolor .42[if odd(i): blue else: red fi, white];
endfor

% finally the labels
label(btex $\phi$   etex, point 1/2 of angle_mark1 scaled 1.23);
label(btex $\theta$ etex, point 1/2 of angle_mark2 scaled 1.23);
label.rt (btex $x$ etex, point 1 of xx);
label.top(btex $y$ etex, point 1 of yy);
fill fullcircle scaled dotlabeldiam;
picture O;
O = thelabel(btex $O$ etex, (u/2,0) rotated (180+45+phi));
unfill bbox O; draw O;

endfig;
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shorter method.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,backgrounds}


\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0pt,p/.style={circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt}]

\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (-3.75,0) +(-0.8cm,0) -- (3.75,0) -- +(0.25cm,0) node[below right] {$x$};

\coordinate[p,label={[fill=white]below right:$O$}] (O) at (0,0);

\draw[draw=blue!30,-latex] (0,0) -- (142:5)coordinate (aa);
\draw[draw=blue!30,-latex] (0,0) -- (-38:4.5)coordinate (cc);
\draw[draw=green!50,-latex] (0,0) -- (52:4.5)coordinate (dd);
\draw[draw=green!50,-latex] (0,0) -- (-128:4.5)coordinate (bb);

\draw[gray,dashed,line width=0.1pt] (aa|-bb) rectangle (cc|-dd);

\coordinate[p,label={[fill=white]below right:$O$}] (O) at (0,0);

\coordinate (A) at (0:1);
\coordinate (B) at (52:1);
\path pic[draw, angle radius=5mm,"$\phi$",angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = A--O--B};

\coordinate (a) at (180:1);
\coordinate (b) at (142:1);
\path pic[draw, angle radius=5mm,"$\theta$",angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = b--O--a};

\coordinate (P) at (142:1);
\coordinate (Q) at (52:1);

\coordinate (R) at ($(O)!4mm! -45:(P)$);
\draw (R) -- ($(O)!(R)!(P)$);
\draw (R) -- ($(O)!(R)!(Q)$);

%The following code makes the right-angle mark and "colors" the inside of it white.
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (0,3.75) +(0,0.25cm) node[above right] {$y$} -- (0,-3.75) -- +(0,-0.25cm);
\filldraw[fill=white] (O.center) -- ($(O)!(R)!(P)$) -- (R) -- ($(O)!(R)!(Q)$) -- cycle;
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

No clipping, no drawing the rectangle piece by piece, no intersection business. Just define coordinates `aa`, `bb` etc, and then use

```
\draw[gray,dashed,line width=0.1pt] (aa|-bb) rectangle (cc|-dd);
```

to draw the rectangle. I have adjusted the length of those lines from `5` to `4.5` BTW.

Since I have some confusion still in my mind, you can draw other lines too like

```
\draw[olive,latex-latex] (aa) -- (bb);
\draw[olive,latex-latex] (aa) -- (dd);
```

[image]

## Edit

To keep `\clip` and find intersections, you have to name the path when it is being drawn. Check the following code.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,quotes,backgrounds,intersections}
%% come back here

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0pt,p/.style={circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt}]

\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (-3.75,0) +(-0.25cm,0) -- (3.75,0) -- +(0.25cm,0) node[below right] {$x$};

\clip (-3.75,-3.75) rectangle (3.75,3.75);

\draw[gray,dashed,line width=0.1pt,name path =A] (-3.75,3.75) -- (3.75,3.75);
\draw[gray,dashed,line width=0.1pt,name path = E] (-3.75,-3.75) -- (3.75,-3.75);
\draw[gray,dashed,line width=0.1pt,name path =G] (-3.75,-3.75) -- (-3.75,3.75);
\draw[gray,dashed,line width=0.1pt,name path=C] (3.75,-3.75) -- (3.75,3.75);

\draw[draw=blue!30,-latex,name path = H] (0,0) -- (142:5);
\draw[draw=blue!30,-latex,name path = D] (0,0) -- (-38:5);
\draw[draw=green!50,-latex,name path=B] (0,0) -- (52:5);
\draw[draw=green!50,-latex,name path =F] (0,0) -- (-128:5);

\coordinate[p,label={[fill=white]below right:$O$}] (O) at (0,0);

\coordinate (A) at (0:1);
\coordinate (B) at (52:1);
\path pic[draw, angle radius=5mm,"$\phi$",angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = A--O--B};

\coordinate (a) at (180:1);
\coordinate (b) at (142:1);
\path pic[draw, angle radius=5mm,"$\theta$",angle eccentricity=1.25] {angle = b--O--a};

\coordinate (P) at (142:1);
\coordinate (Q) at (52:1);

\coordinate (R) at ($(O)!4mm! -45:(P)$);
\draw (R) -- ($(O)!(R)!(P)$);
\draw (R) -- ($(O)!(R)!(Q)$);

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (0,3.75) +(0,0.25cm) node[above right] {$y$} -- (0,-3.75) -- +(0,-0.25cm);
\filldraw[fill=white] (O.center) -- ($(O)!(R)!(P)$) -- (R) -- ($(O)!(R)!(Q)$) -- cycle;
\end{scope}

    %The following code is for placing arrowheads at the ends of the line segments.
    \path[name intersections={of= A and B, by=aa}];
    \path[name intersections={of=C  and D, by=bb}];
    \path[name intersections={of= E and F, by=cc}];
    \path[name intersections={of= G and H, by=dd}];
    \draw[draw=green!30,latex-latex] (O) -- (aa);
    \draw[draw=blue!30,latex-latex] (O) -- (bb);
    \draw[draw=green!50,latex-latex] (O) -- (cc);
    \draw[draw=blue!30,latex-latex] (O) -- (dd);



\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like the code; I would like to refer to it for other situations.  With your code, the lines are bounded by a rectangle, which is not a square. (The code `\draw[gray,dashed,line width=0.1pt] (aa|-bb) rectangle (cc|-dd);` instructs `TikZ` to plot a rectangle with a lower left vertex of `aa|-bb` - a coordinate at the point of intersection of a vertical line through aa and a horizontal line through bb - and an upper right vertex of `cc|-dd` - a coordinate at the point of intersection of a vertical line through cc and a horizontal line through dd.

Comment: In this case, I would like to keep the lines in a square and not just any rectangle.  Using the `intersections` package is quite convenient for this.  I have the code - I just don't know why it is not getting compiled.

Comment: May you fix the code?  I put "%" in front of the last six commands so that the code would compile. What is wrong with the way I issued the commands?

Comment: @user74973 See the last edit.